# How do I import modules in a project using pyodide without errors?

Tags: javascript, python, pyodide

Whenever I import python modules in a pyodide, it gives this error.

```
pyodide.js:108 Invalid package name or URI
```

I am not sure how to properly import modules,
I have tried this which was mentioned in the docs.

```
pyodide.loadPackage('<module address>')
```

(this returns a promise on whoes resolution I run this method)

```
pyodide.runPython('
                   <python code here>
                ')
```

Upon execution, I get the error mentioned above.

Javascript Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          // set the pyodide files URL (packages.json, pyodide.asm.data etc)
          window.languagePluginUrl = 'https://pyodide-cdn2.iodide.io/v0.15.0/full/';
      </script>
      <script src="https://pyodide-cdn2.iodide.io/v0.15.0/full/pyodide.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Pyodide test page <br>
    Open your browser console to see pyodide output
    <script type="text/javascript">
          languagePluginLoader.then(function () {
            pyodide.loadPackage('<address>').then(() => {
                    console.log(pyodide.runPython('
                    import sys
                    from <my package> import *
                    sys.version
                '));
                console.log(pyodide.runPython('print(1 + 2)'));
            });
            
          });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is a chance that this question might be unclear, but please let me know if you have trouble understanding something.

Also, the string passed in the `runPython()` method is the python code, just to avoid confusion.

I even tried uploading the module to a server as the docs mentioned a URL using the HTTP protocol, was pretty stupid trying this but I did.

Docs: https://pyodide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using_pyodide_from_javascript.html#loading-packages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update: Pyodide v0.21.0**

Starting with Pyodide 0.18.0, [runPythonAsync](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/js-api.html#pyodide.runPythonAsync) does not automatically load packages, so [loadPackagesFromImports](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/js-api.html#pyodide.loadPackagesFromImports) should be called beforehand.

So, to import a third-party package like `numpy` we have two options: we can either pre-load required packages manually and then import them in Python

```js
// JS

await pyodide.loadPackage('numpy');
// numpy is now available
pyodide.runPython('import numpy as np')
console.log(pyodide.runPython('np.ones((3, 3)))').toJs())
```

or we can use the [loadPackagesFromImports](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/js-api.html#pyodide.loadPackagesFromImports) function that will automatically download all packages that the code snippet imports:

```js
// JS
let python_code = `
import numpy as np
np.ones((3,3))
`
(async () => { // enable await
  await pyodide.loadPackagesFromImports(python_code)
  let result = await pyodide.runPythonAsync(python_code)
  console.log(result.toJs())
})() // call the function immediately
```

More examples can be found [here](https://karay.me/2022/07/12/bringing-python-to-the-web.html)

```js
(async () => { // enable await
  let python_code = `
import numpy as np
np.ones((3,3))
`
  let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
  await pyodide.loadPackagesFromImports(python_code)
  console.log(pyodide.runPython(python_code).toJs())
})() // call the function immediately
```

```html
<script src="https://pyodide-cdn2.iodide.io/v0.21.0/full/pyodide.js"></script>
```

Note also, that starting with version 0.17, Pyodide uses JsProxy for non-JS datatypes. So, before printing the results, it has to be converted using [toJs](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/js-api.html#PyProxy.toJs).

---

**Old answer (related to Pyodide v0.15.0)**

It is not clear what you are passing as `<address>` in `pyodide.loadPackage('<address>')`, but it should just be the package name (e.g. `numpy`).

Also, note that Pyodide currently supports a limited number of packages. Check out this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@karray/python-in-web-easy-5f7de3813055) on it for more details.

If you want to import a third-party package like `numpy` there are two options: you can either pre-load required packages manually and then import them in Python using `pyodide.loadPackage` and `pyodide.runPython` functions:

```js
pyodide.loadPackage('numpy').then(() => {
  // numpy is now available
  pyodide.runPython('import numpy as np')
  console.log(pyodide.runPython('np.ones((3, 3)))'))
})
```

Or you can use `pyodide.runPythonAsync` function that will automatically download all packages that the code snippet imports.

Here is the minimal example for `pyodide.runPythonAsync`

```js
let python_code = `
import numpy as np
np.ones((3,3))
`
// init environment, then run python code
languagePluginLoader.then(() => {
    pyodide.runPythonAsync(python_code).then(output => alert(output))
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Default Pyodide files URL ('packages.json', 'pyodide.asm.data', etc.)
    window.languagePluginUrl = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide//v0.15.0/full/';
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.15.0/full/pyodide.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that the `runPythonAsync` technique doesn't work on v0.18.0+ anymore. [Ref](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/project/changelog.html#id18)