# How to send a message from index.html to Vue.js 3 instance?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex, pyodide

So, imagine Vue `index.html` that also loads some custom script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
    languagePluginLoader.then(function () {
        pyodide.loadPackage("someName").then(() => {
            // Send message to Vue that everything is fine
        }).catch((err) => {
            // Send message to Vue that it failed
        })
    })
    </script>
    ...
    ...
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to communicate with running Vue instance or/and Vuex from the `index.html` file? For example, I want to show "Loading..." until the script is fully loaded, etc.

- One way will be to send the message to the service worker and then from the service worker to Vue, but it feels unpractical.
- Another way is to set `windows.script_status = true` after the initialization, but `window` object is not reactive, so Vue will check it once, get `undefined` and forget about it.
- UPD: Third way will be to inject scripts from the Vue side and put some function into `script.onload` to get when it's ready, but not sure how stable the solution is.

So, any advice will do :)

Comment: I suggest you to use `pyodide.runPythonAsync`. This function will automatically download all import-packages. You still have to wait until the `pyodide` is initialized though. Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64418958/2329060)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the third one - inject script manually through `mounted` and put all the logic into `script.onload` part. Google Maps example:

```
mounted: function () {
    if (window.google && window.google.maps) {
        this.create_map();
        return;
    }

    var self = this;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.onload = function () {
        if (!window.google && !window.google.maps)
            return void (console.error("no google maps script included"));

        self.create_map();
    };

    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=googleapikeyxxxx&callback=initMap";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Picked the logic **from another SO question's answer**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45605316/1598470.

Comment: The important part - if you want to update component variable from `data` in `.then()` part - reassign `let self = this` at the start (as in the example above), because each `.then()` has its own `this` :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go the route of an external event hub. Since Vue 3 removed the $on, $off and $once instance methods, the official [migration strategy](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#migration-strategy) for an event hub is to use an external library, such as [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt). Using e.g. mitt you should be able to signal Vue easily once your other custom scripts have been loaded.

Comment: Thanks, never heard about `mitt`, looks legit :)

Comment: Used `mitt` for the first time recently, works like a charm and with 200 bytes gzipped footprint it was a no-brainer for me.